# Primefaces の DataExporter による PDF 出力で日本語を出力する

Tags: java, 文字化け, pdf, 日本語, primefaces

[PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) の [DataExporter](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml)で PDF を出力すると日本語が表示されません。

以下のような対応を実施してみましたが、解決できていません。

- `iTextAsian.jar` をプロジェクトに組み込み
- [primefaces-extensions](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/home.jsf) の [exporter](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/exporter.jsf) を利用し、
  `fontName=HeiseiKakuGo-W5,encording=UniJIS-UCS2-H` を指定

対処方法をご存知の方がいれば教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ドキュメントが見当たらないので Primefaces Extensions のソース見てみました。
https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/exporter/PDFExporter.java
createCustomFonts の 917行目 の箇所が問題のようです。

```
if (fontName != null && FontFactory.getFont(fontName).getBaseFont() != null) {
    this.cellFont = FontFactory.getFont(fontName, encoding);
    this.facetFont = FontFactory.getFont(fontName, encoding, Font.DEFAULTSIZE, Font.BOLD);
} else {
    this.cellFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES, encoding);
    this.facetFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES, encoding, Font.DEFAULTSIZE, Font.BOLD);
}
```

`FontFactory.getFont` が fontName しか渡していないので "HeiseiKakuGo-W5" Font が取れず else の方に流れているようです。  
ここを以下のように書き換えると動きそうですが、PrimeFaces Extensions をビルドしないとダメなので大変な感じですね。

```
if (fontName != null && FontFactory.getFont(fontName, encoding).getBaseFont() != null) {
```

一応、iText の field をいじる方法で日本語出ました。

ダウンロードをする前のどこかのタイミングで

```
FontFactory.defaultEncoding = "UniJIS-UCS2-H";
```

をしておけば日本語出力されました。

iText 詳しくないのでどんな影響が出るかは分かりませんが、解決の糸口になればと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。頂いた情報をヒントに対応してみます。